# $C_0$ is a closed subespace of $l_\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Could anyone help me to prove is this statement is true or false?
Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210006/is-this-proof-that-c-0-is-a-closed-subspace-of-ell-infty-correct-also-nee?noredirect=1&lq=1 there is a solution here.

Comment: [One line solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/708126/253273)