# When denoting a sequence, what does the superscript and subscript mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I am having trouble understanding the answer in this question:
[Is this proof that $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$ correct? Also need some help finish it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210006/is-this-proof-that-c-0-is-a-closed-subspace-of-ell-infty-correct-also-nee)

In the first answer by Alonso Delfín, what does the n in closed bracket as superscript mean? I know that sequences are denoted as as x subscript n. Finally, in the fourth line of the answer, it is shown to have both, superscript, (n) and subscript, j on x. If someone can clarify what these mean with an example, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is written that $(x^k)$ is a *sequence of sequences*. This means that **every** $x^k$ is in turn a sequence: $x^K= (a_1^k, a_2^k, \ldots)$ where each $a_i^k$ is a number.

Comment: Thank you but I am talking about the one in the first answer, where we have x superscript (n) and then also with j as a subscript. I am getting confused. An example would be very helpful. @MauroALLEGRANZA